# A word for picking out minor mistakes in a discussion

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language

The act of picking out minor mistakes in a discussion, it is being "xxxxx".

Comment: nitpicky?  (minimum comment length achieved)

Comment: *nitpicking*; being a *quibbler, niggler fault-finder, hyper-critic, caviller/ caviler* ...

Comment: [picky](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/picky?q=picky)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Hellion suggested, [nitpicking](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/nitpicking) or nitpicky would be good, but [pedantic](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pedantic) means the same thing, more or less, and is much more common as this [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=nitpicking,%20nitpicky,pedantic&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,nitpicking;,c0;.t1;,nitpicky;,c0;.t1;,pedantic;,c0) shows.

Comment: +1. I would favour *nitpicking* when the minor point isn't actually relevant, and *pedantic* when it's relevant but still minor.

Comment: Nitpicking is a less formal term for 'being pedantic', I agree with @Jon Hanna that their common use suggests nitpicking is well suited to someone objecting to a misspelt word in an otherwise syntactically correct and logically valid sentence, where pedantic would be objecting to a minor logical inconsistency or unhandled detail that isn't relevant to the overarching point.

Comment: Pedantic was precisely the phrase I was looking for. Thanks!